# How to make Redis save LRU data to disk?

Tags: redis, jedis

How can I make `REDIS`save least recently used data to disk in order to save some memory?

I have seen the documentation of `REDIS` but I only found how to set the memory limit to a specific amount of MB and the all eviction policies say that when a new item should be inserted to the database old ones should be deleted, but I need them to be stored in the disk, how can I do that?

Comment: Redis is an in - memory database and as such it stores ALL data in RAM. Disk is (optionally) used only to persist the data, so that if and when there's a failure/shutdown, data is loaded to RAM after restarting Redis. There's no way in standard Redis to do what you're skiing for.

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer to this is not to use Redis, but instead to use a [Redis compatible database like Ardb](https://github.com/yinqiwen/ardb/issues/26) which in turn can be configured to use LevelDB under the hood which [supports LRU type on-disk caches](https://github.com/yinqiwen/ardb/issues/26).